# Is there a way to benchmark crypto libraries so that the results are hardware independent?

Tags: security, encryption, cryptography

Is there a way to benchmark crypto libraries so that the results are hardware independent?

Comment: I'm not sure where the results would be valid.  If a library performs well on x86 and terribly on ARM, why would you want to abstract that out to say that it performs so-so across the board?  Similarly, if all you are ever going to use it on is x86, why would you care if it performs terribly on ARM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To benchmark algorithms on x86 machine in a **frequency independent** way we use to count  **CPU cycles** rather than time. Not sure if ARM suport such feature, if so, you can have solve your problem using some conditional code like:

```
uint64_t get_cycles()
{
#ifdef _INTEL_X86
// return CPU cycle count with x86 specific code
// read tim stamp counter instruction rdtsc() for instance
#endif
#ifdef _ARM
// return CPU cycle count with ARM specific code
#endif
}

uint64_t start, stop, tot_cycles;
start = get_cycles();
// code to benchmark
stop = get_cycles()
tot_cycles = stop - start;
```

Hope this might help.

Comment: I don't see how this is hardware independent. Like @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams said, libraries can make use of CPU features to speed up their algorithms.  Consider the new processors that actually have an AES instruction.  A library that can leverage that instruction will almost definitely take fewer clock cycles on a processor that supports it.

Comment: @Luke: As I understand the question, Daniel Gartmann is not asking for some code that runs on the same speed on any machine, but a way to benchmark the same code on different hw architecture. If his code works faster on X86 rather than on some other CPU, because of special instructions [like AESNI] the above benchmark will show that ;)

Comment: Perhaps you are correct, but that's not how I would define "hardware independent".  If that is what he meant, then he should have asked, "How can I compare the performance of different encryption libraries across multiple architectures?"  He did accept your answer though, so I guess he just phrased the question poorly.  To me, I thought he was after a method to benchmark an algorithm on Platform A and imply results on Platform B (without explicitly testing on Platform B).  That, as I think we both agree, cannot be done.

Answer (score 3):

No. Many libraries will make use of various CPU facilities in order to speed up their algorithms, thereby making hardware-independent benchmarks impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Use different hardware environments and calculate averages. I guess you'll also find useful information which lib suits your needs best on the net without doing benchmarks yourself.